# Ant and XML-based Spring security integration (without using annotations)

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, spring-security

I am newbie to Spring .I built a spring MVC application which is XML based and I used JAR files using [Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).

Now I have to integrate spring security in it. I found many tutorials for spring security, but all are made using annotations. And in the MVC tutorial it uses Ant and XML. I am just lost in this part. Should I have to convert my whole application using annotations or what to do?

Is there any way using spring security without annotations? May be this question is not logical. But guide me and help me solve my confusion.

Or is there any tutorial help me in this regard, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with using annotations?

Comment: What I am asking that ok I will use annotations, but should I have to change my application to annotation base or Spring security have no concern in which type your application is made?

Comment: You don't need to use annotations to use Spring Security, but it's far easier to do it that way.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thanks. But can you tell me how to do it or is there any tutoriall or link that might help me in this regard, kindly share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "change my application to annotation base", but you will have to add some anotations above your methods like this:

```
@Secured("isAuthenticated() and hasRole('PERMISSION_BUY_ITEMS')")
public void buyItem(int itemId, int userId) {
   // you buy stuff login
}
```

This way in order to access your method the user should be logged in (authenticated) and have the permission `BUY_ITEMS`.

You don't have to do this for all your methods.

If you do not need permission/role based authorization you can just use authentication based expressions like `isAuthenticated()`, `isAnonymous()` and `permitAll` out of the box without any custom implementation.